# How do I capture the full dimensions of a pdf table and convert it using Camelot in Python?

Tags: python, pypdf, python-camelot

[pdf link](https://audit.kpmg.us/articles/2020/illustrative-financial-statements-2020.html)I have been trying to use the Camelot library and trying to capture a table (that isn't really formatted as a table) by setting the flavor parameter to 'stream'. However, it is not detecting the entire table. So what I decided to do is try to detect the entire page by feeding it an area parameter that takes the pages dimensions as inputs.

I have tried using this code but it still does not give me the whole page dimensions.

```
import camelot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2

pdf_file = open(r'C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\finstate.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
page = pdf_reader.getPage(10)
width = page.mediaBox.getWidth()
height = page.mediaBox.getHeight()
print("Width:", width)
print("Height:", height)

page_area = [0, 0, 0, 0]
pdf = camelot.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\finstate.pdf', pages='0-10', flavor='stream', area=page_area)
first_table = pdf[10]

print(first_table.df)
first_table.to_csv(r'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\table.csv')
```

Comment: Can you provide the PDF? ***stream*** parsing method should be used to extract tables without borders. Is your table a table without any border between its cells and has sufficient margin between the content of cells? If not, then you can try ***lattice*** as parsing method to extract table in better way.

Comment: Thank you for replying back! I have edited my post in the beginning to include the file.

Comment: I guess I put the wrong link but any of the 2 reports work, so the page is irrelevant. Any page with a table in it is what causes me problems. I am not an expert at python so I did not really understand your explanation, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the pdf. As I see, your flavor choice is ok for your tables. So forget about my comment and I will try to write an answer wich could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

To improve the detected area, you can increase the edge_tol (default: 50) value to counter the effect of text being placed relatively far apart vertically. Larger edge_tol will lead to longer text edges being detected, leading to an improved guess of the table area. Let’s use a value of 500.

You can try the following code. If it doesn't work play with edge_tol;

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\finstate.pdf', pages='0-10', flavor='stream', edge_tol=500)
```

And the following code snippet could be helpful how your table detected is;

```
camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='contour').show()
```

Comment: Hey thank you for replying Said. I am kind of stuck, why does'nt the code work
import camelot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2

pdf_file = open(r'C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\finstate.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

pdf = camelot.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\finstate.pdf', pages='0-10', flavor='stream', edge_tol=500)

camelot.plot(pdf, kind='contour').show()

Comment: What is the Error message?

Comment: Pls, provide code surrounded in backticks  "```"